# Access Database/Model Objects During Assets Precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my rails chat application to Heroku, but my javascript can't make a call to the database during asset precompile.  The push fails with a *"Precompiling assets failed."*

Following the trace, I find

```rb
remote:        Caused by:
remote:        PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "chatrooms" does not exist
remote:        LINE 1: SELECT "chatrooms".* FROM "chatrooms"
```

After some investigation, I found that `Chatroom.all.each` is whats causing trouble.

**Channel (client side):**

```js
// my-app/app/assets/javascripts/channels/chatroom.js.erb

//Iterate through chatrooms
<% Chatroom.all.each do |chatroom| %>

  App['chatroom' + <%= chatroom.id %>] = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: "ChatroomChannel", room: <%= chatroom.id %>},{    

      received: function(data) {
          ...
      };

  });

<% end %>
```

So I can't seem to access the Chatroom model during precompile. Is there something I need to put in my *production.rb* file? The app works fine in my local environment.

Comment: What did you do when you 'tried resetting the database on Heroku'?

Comment: I entered `$ heroku pg:reset` followed by `$ heroku run rails db:migrate` in the terminal

Comment: it sounds almost as though its trying to create chatroom_users before chatrooms is created.  Did you double check that your migrations aren't out of order?

Comment: They look to be in the correct order. From earliest to latest timestamp, my migrations are: _create_users.rb_, _create_messages.rb_, _create_chatrooms.rb_, _create_chatroom_users.rb_, and _add_chatroom_id_to_users.rb_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no way of accessing the database while the assets precompile.

I worked around it by instead storing the chatroom IDs in HTML5 data attributes, and using jQuery to iterate through them.

```js
// my-app/app/assets/javascripts/channels/chatroom.js.erb

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () => {

  //Iterate through chatrooms
  $('.message-container').each(function() {

    App[`chatroom${$(this).data('chatroom_id')}`] = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: "ChatroomChannel", room: String($(this).data('chatroom_id'))},{

      received: function(data) {
        ...
      }

    });
  });
})
```

I'm open to other solutions though!